# OpenInputStream Returning file not found exception but the file is there

Tags: android

I am trying to scale a bitmap from an SD card and write it to phone memory. Then decode it at a later point to add it to `HashMap`.

The problem is that I am getting file not found exception although the path is right and the scaled image exists (I checked that)

Here is the saving part

```
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options );         
        File imageRootPath = getFilesDir();
        File imageRoot = new File(imageRootPath, imagUri.getLastPathSegment()+".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageRoot);
        yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

And here is the part when I read the file

```
try {
Uri mainImgeUri = Uri.parse(imageRoot.toString());
File imageFile = new File(mainImgeUri.toString());
if(imageFile.exists()){
   System.out.println("it does");
}
InputStream imageStream = ListPropertiesBaseActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mainImgeUri); // I am getting file not found error

Bitmap yourSelectedImage =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
hmBitmap.put(ID, yourSelectedImage);
imageStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Could it be that `OpenInputStream` can not read from internal phone memory? Or may be the image that resulted from saving is not good?

Although I was able to view it by manually browsing to the file and opening it

Please note that the System.out.Println is executed so it means the file exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Logging imageStream to see what the uri actually is?

Comment: Well since I am getting an exception at the line that is populating imageStream then it is not even populated

Comment: I am concerned that parsing a URI from imageRoot.toString() won't give you a actual uri to the location of the File. 
You could try Uri mainImgeUri = Uri.fromFile(imageRoot) to get an actual file:// uri to use with openInputStream.

Comment: I logged the URI and it is has the correct path. I will update my code with something else

Comment: Could you paste the Uri Log here? It has to comply with either the content, android.resource or file Uri schemes to work with openInputStream. Uri.fromFile(imageRoot) with give you a valid file uri.

Comment: This is the URI /data/data/com.myproj.testapp/files/3555.png    but I found an answer (well an alternative), check below

Comment: The Uri should look like file:///data/data/com.myproj.testapp/files/3555.png otherwise it will not be recognised as a file location. If you use Uri.fromFile(imageRoot) it should give you a valid file Uri.

Comment: And you are absolutely right!!!!. It worked! It is weird that Uri.Parse didn't work. I will accept your answer. Thank you.. By the way doe you recommend

Answer (score 1):

create a `File` object using you `mainImgeUri` uri and check file exists or not, the pass this file to `openInputStream()` method

Comment: I put the code to check if the file exists or not. And it does. OpenInputStream accepts URI only so  Ican't pass the file but the file exists

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND IT. Well I found a way around it but I was never able to explain the previous behviour and why it won't work. I replaced this getContentResolver with

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
Bitmap yourSelectedImage =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

This worked. Any idea why! though